# Moving a form to jQueryMobile broke the javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a form in which the javascript worked correctly before I ported it into jquery mobile.

There is a jsFiddle of it at http://jsfiddle.net/wynnwade/YrJRy/.

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>iSTAFF</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/jqm132/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jqm_site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">

    <style type="text/css">
        /* Smartphone Styling */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
            #splashLogo img{ width: 90%; }
        } /* END SMARTPHONE STYLING */
        @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
            .ui-li-desc {
                margin: -2em 0 0 1.5em;
            }
        }
        .invalid { border-color: #B00400; border-width: 2px;}
    </style>

    <script src="/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
            $. mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        }); // END document.bind
    </script>
    <script src="/jqm132/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head> 
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Primrose Everdeen</h1>
        <a href="http://istaff.edrtest.com/staff/proforms" data-icon="arrow-l">FORMS</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">  
        <div class="jqm-home-welcome">
            <h2>PURCHASE ORDER REQUEST</h2>
        </div>
        <form action="http://istaff.edrtest.com/staff/pro_amex_handler" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="raFName">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="raFName" name="raFName" value="Primrose" />
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="raLName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="raLName" name="raLName" value="Everdeen" />
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">  
            <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="peverdeen@edrtrust.com" />
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="location" class="select">Location:</label>
            <select id="location" name="location">
                <option>Please select ...</option>
                                    <option value="1">Betty White Plaza - Front Desk</options>
                                    <option value="2">Betty White Plaza - Gym</options>
                                    <option value="5">Common Convention Center - Concierge</options>
                                    <option value="4">Common Convention Center - Front Desk</options>
                            </select>
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="vendor">Vendor/Store/Location:</label>
            <input type="text" id="vendor" name="vendor" value="" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:55%;">Item(detailed description)</th>
                    <th style="width:15%;">Quantity</th>
                    <th style="width:15%;">Unit Price</th>
                    <th style="width:15%;">Total</th>
                </tr>
                                    <tr class="itemRow">
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="i1-desc"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td class="qty">
                            <input type="text" id="i1-quantity" name="i1-quantity" value="0" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="price">
                            <input type="text" name="i1-unit-price" value="0.00" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="line_total">
                            <input type="text" name="i1-total" id="i1-total" class="inTotal" value="0.00" disabled="disabled" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="itemRow">
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="i2-desc"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td class="qty">
                            <input type="text" id="i2-quantity" name="i2-quantity" value="0" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="price">
                            <input type="text" name="i2-unit-price" value="0.00" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="line_total">
                            <input type="text" name="i2-total" id="i2-total" class="inTotal" value="0.00" disabled="disabled" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="itemRow">
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="i3-desc"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td class="qty">
                            <input type="text" id="i3-quantity" name="i3-quantity" value="0" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="price">
                            <input type="text" name="i3-unit-price" value="0.00" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="line_total">
                            <input type="text" name="i3-total" id="i3-total" class="inTotal" value="0.00" disabled="disabled" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="itemRow">
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="i4-desc"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td class="qty">
                            <input type="text" id="i4-quantity" name="i4-quantity" value="0" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="price">
                            <input type="text" name="i4-unit-price" value="0.00" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="line_total">
                            <input type="text" name="i4-total" id="i4-total" class="inTotal" value="0.00" disabled="disabled" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="itemRow">
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="i5-desc"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td class="qty">
                            <input type="text" id="i5-quantity" name="i5-quantity" value="0" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="price">
                            <input type="text" name="i5-unit-price" value="0.00" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="line_total">
                            <input type="text" name="i5-total" id="i5-total" class="inTotal" value="0.00" disabled="disabled" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="itemRow">
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="i6-desc"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td class="qty">
                            <input type="text" id="i6-quantity" name="i6-quantity" value="0" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="price">
                            <input type="text" name="i6-unit-price" value="0.00" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="line_total">
                            <input type="text" name="i6-total" id="i6-total" class="inTotal" value="0.00" disabled="disabled" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="itemRow">
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="i7-desc"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td class="qty">
                            <input type="text" id="i7-quantity" name="i7-quantity" value="0" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="price">
                            <input type="text" name="i7-unit-price" value="0.00" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="line_total">
                            <input type="text" name="i7-total" id="i7-total" class="inTotal" value="0.00" disabled="disabled" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="itemRow">
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="i8-desc"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td class="qty">
                            <input type="text" id="i8-quantity" name="i8-quantity" value="0" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="price">
                            <input type="text" name="i8-unit-price" value="0.00" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="line_total">
                            <input type="text" name="i8-total" id="i8-total" class="inTotal" value="0.00" disabled="disabled" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                <tr style="background-color:#333;height:5px;font-size:0px;">
                    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"> --- </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="text" id="numberItems" name="numberItems" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"> --- </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="text" id="totalPrice" name="totalPrice" value="0.00" disabled="disabled" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="text-align:center;">   
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND FORM" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" class="footer-docs" data-position="fixed">
        <h4><em>iSTAFF</em></h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        $('.price').on('blur', 'input', function(e){
            var thisQ = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).children('input').val();
            var thisP = $(this).val();
            var thisT = parseFloat(thisQ) * parseFloat(thisP);
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.inTotal').empty().val( parseFloat(thisT).toFixed(2));

            running_total();
        });
    })(); // end self-invoking anonymous function

    function running_total(){
        var n1 = $('#i1-quantity').val();
        var n2 = $('#i2-quantity').val();
        var n3 = $('#i3-quantity').val();
        var n4 = $('#i4-quantity').val();
        var n5 = $('#i5-quantity').val();
        var n6 = $('#i6-quantity').val();
        var n7 = $('#i7-quantity').val();
        var n8 = $('#i8-quantity').val();

        var rCnt = parseFloat(n1)+parseFloat(n2)+parseFloat(n3)+parseFloat(n4)+parseFloat(n5)+parseFloat(n6)+parseFloat(n7)+parseFloat(n8);
        $('#numberItems').val( parseFloat(rCnt) );

        var t1 = $('#i1-total').val();
        var t2 = $('#i2-total').val();
        var t3 = $('#i3-total').val();
        var t4 = $('#i4-total').val();
        var t5 = $('#i5-total').val();
        var t6 = $('#i6-total').val();
        var t7 = $('#i7-total').val();
        var t8 = $('#i8-total').val();

        var rTot = parseFloat(t1)+parseFloat(t2)+parseFloat(t3)+parseFloat(t4)+parseFloat(t5)+parseFloat(t6)+parseFloat(t7)+parseFloat(t8);
        $('#totalPrice').val( parseFloat(rTot).toFixed(2) );
    } // end function
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The issue is that jQuery Mobile can no longer find the "total" cell to put the product of unit * unit_price since jqueryMobile add in divs and other elements for cool mobile styling.

Any help or suggestion of resource is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try the modifications below? should be working.

```
    (function() {
        $('.price').on('blur', 'input', function(e){
            // var thisQ = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).children('input').val();
            var thisQ = $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty input').val();

            var thisP = $(this).val();
            var thisT = parseFloat(thisQ) * parseFloat(thisP);
            // $(this).closest('tr').find('.inTotal').empty().val( parseFloat(thisT).toFixed(2));
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.inTotal').val( parseFloat(thisT).toFixed(2));


            running_total();
        });
    })(); // end self-invoking anonymous function
```